# What do you call this kind of shoes

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, word-usage

This is the picture

[image]

What is the name in English please?

(This is that we wear at home.)

Do you also know the name of the closed version of this? I mean that one that doesn't show the toes.

Comment: [Flip-flops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flops). It is said that the name comes from the sound these shoes make when walking.

Comment: Very practical hint: For problems like this one, go to the corresponding Wikipedia article in your language (Italian?), then switch to the language you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "that doesn't show the toes?" I think that would need more explanation and could lead to another answer...

Comment: Flip-flops have a flat spongy rubber sole, and they float in water.  These flip-flops are a slightly more decorative version with bead-work "uppers".

Answer (score 2):

Flip-flops, or sandals.

(Sorry for the short length of this answer, but there's not much more to explain)

Answer (score 2):

They are flip-flops. Where I live, older people sometimes still call them "thongs", which was an older name for them that fell out of use when thong underwear became popular. Be aware that you might hear them referred to this way, but it is best to use "flip-flops" yourself.

Comment: 'Thongs' is the common name in Australian English.  'Flip-Flops' in most other places.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **flip-flops**, have a look at this [Google image search](https://www.google.be/search?q=flip-flop&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=802&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CEMQsARqFQoTCIigsbPXzcYCFcI9FAodUOoJtw) as a source.

The general name for these kind of slip-in shoes, that you *slip* your foot in and out, is **slipper**.
See this [Google image search](https://www.google.be/search?q=slippers&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=802&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDEQsARqFQoTCNn-3frXzcYCFQOC2wodt3QBaw) and this [definition from Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slipper):

> a light low-cut shoe that is easily slipped on the foot

Comment: In the UK, a slipper is a shoe that you wear around the house.

Comment: @SteveIves - it always puzzled me as a child why Cinderella wore slippers to go to a party - I always had this mental picture of fluffy bunny feet made of glass ;)

Comment: I think "slip-on" or "loafer" might be better than slipper, which could be confused with the [fuzzy type](http://www.forlifeandstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Fuzzy-Slippers_06.jpg).

Comment: Slippers has two meanings in the US, the shoe worn around the house (often fur-lined) and elegant shoes worn with ball gowns, often little more than a few straps.  Dorothy in the *Wizard of Oz* wears "ruby slippers" but few slippers of either variety look like that nowadays. http://americanhistory.si.edu/press/fact-sheets/ruby-slippers

Answer (score 1):

While I've never thought of them as a closed version of flip-flops, shoes with an open back and a covered toe are called [mules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(shoe)).